# What controls are used for making terminal using C# and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm developing a Terminal Software that send command and data, receive log and data, etc...

Terminal S/W communicate with Arm Cortex via USB Interface.

For developing, I used C# and WPF textbox for terminal screen.
But, I faced some problem.

Updating textbox is very slow compared to USB interfaced.

How can I solve this problem?

If you have solutions or know usercontrol made by WPF for terminal.

Please let me know.

Thank you.

Additional Infomation.

1.string property for binding to TextBox

```
public string TestString
{
    get { return _testString; }
    set
    {
        _testString = value;
        RaisePropertyChangedEvent("TestString");
    }
}
```

2.test functions for updating log

```
StringBuilder testBulider = new StringBuilder();
testBulider.Capacity = 1000000;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    testBulider.Append(i.ToString("x4") + "\n");
    testString = testBulider.ToString();    // Very Slow Point
}
```

3.Capture of performance analyzer result in VS2012
[image]

Comment: What have you tired so far please provide that.

Comment: I added additional information.

Comment: Build your own control that renders text (or text *lines*) in an immutable way.

Comment: as a workaround you could use an 'async' method to update the textbox. It'll still take long for the textbox to render everything, but the actual work will be unaffected from that.

Comment: What happens in your RaisePropertyChangedEvent?

Answer (score 2):

StringBuilder may not be the way to go here, and is typically used when you are appending a lot of data in a loop or other process, and wish to call ToString at the very end.  The performance is better in that case than say, doing a bunch of explicit string concatenations because of the memory allocation overhead.

I'm not entirely certain on your application but I'd guess you just want to display some output from the terminal. I'd suggest you store the lines of text in an ObservableCollection property and add to it as you receive new lines.  I do something similar and have an extended RichTextBox with a DataSource property that I use to display the lines.  I'm sure there are faster ways to do this (RichTextBox is NOT known for its performance, and I'm constructing a new inline block every time a line is added), but I've never noticed any performance issues - and it allowed me to get creative with color coding formatted based on event type etc.

Anyway, I've tried my best to copy what I have while stripping out my specific implementation details, I didn't test this specifically.

EventLogBox class:

```
public class EventLogBox : RichTextBox
{
    public EventLogBox()
    {

    }


    static EventLogBox()
    {
        RichTextBox.IsReadOnlyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(EventLogBox),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true));

        RichTextBox.VerticalScrollBarVisibilityProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(EventLogBox),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(ScrollBarVisibility.Visible));

        RichTextBox.FontFamilyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(EventLogBox),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new FontFamily("Courier New")));
    }



    private void AddItem(string pEntry)
    {
        Paragraph a = new Paragraph();
        Run messageRun = new Run(pEntry);
        a.Inlines.Add(messageRun);

        this.Document.Blocks.Add(a);
        this.ScrollToEnd();
    }

    private void LoadNewItems()
    {
        this.Document.Blocks.Clear();
        foreach (string entry in DataSource)
        {
            this.AddItem(entry);
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    ///     The source of content (EventLogEntrys)
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<string> DataSource
    {
        get
        {
            return (IEnumerable<string>)GetValue(DataSourceProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(DataSourceProperty, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for <see cref="DataSource"/>.
    ///     This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register
        (
            "DataSource",
            typeof(IEnumerable<string>), typeof(EventLogBox),
            new PropertyMetadata
            (
                new ObservableQueue<string>(),
                new PropertyChangedCallback(DataSourcePropertyChanged)
            ),
            new ValidateValueCallback(IsValidDataSourceProperty)
        );

    /// <summary>
    /// We also ned to impliment the INotifyCollectionChanged interface
    /// in order for everything to work properly.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pValue"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static bool IsValidDataSourceProperty(object pValue)
    {
        return pValue is INotifyCollectionChanged;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Callback when the DataSourceProperty changes. Setup the new
    /// CollectionChanged events, etc.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pSender"></param>
    /// <param name="pArgs"></param>
    private static void DataSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject pSender,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs pArgs)
    {
        EventLogBox s = ((EventLogBox)pSender);
        ((INotifyCollectionChanged)s.DataSource).CollectionChanged -=
            new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(
                s.DataSource_CollectionChanged);
        ((INotifyCollectionChanged)s.DataSource).CollectionChanged +=
            new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(
                s.DataSource_CollectionChanged);
        s.LoadNewItems();
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pSender"></param>
    /// <param name="pArgs"></param>
    private void DataSource_CollectionChanged(object pSender,
        NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs pArgs)
    {
        IList n = pArgs.NewItems;

        switch (pArgs.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                {
                    foreach (string cle in pArgs.NewItems)
                    {
                        AddItem(cle);
                    }

                    break;
                }
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                {
                    for (int i = pArgs.OldStartingIndex;
                         i < pArgs.OldItems.Count; i++)
                    {
                        this.Document.Blocks.Remove(this.Document.Blocks.ElementAt(i));
                    }

                    break;
                }
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                {
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Property In ViewModel

```
private ObservableCollection<string> mLines = new ObservableCollection<string>();

public ObservableCollection<string> Lines
{
    get
    {
        return mLines;
    }
}
```

In XAML:

```
<local:EventLogBox DataSource="{Binding Path=Lines}" Height="100"/>
```

Then when you receive a new line from your terminal, call

```
Lines.Add(newLine);
```

Comment: If formatting isn't needed, or on a per-line basis, a simple ItemsControl bound to the collection with the item template being just a TextBlock would probably be lighter-weight than a RichTextBox.

Comment: I agree.  I needed pretty complex formatting (I have extended runs as well that handle this).  I also needed document-like text selection, saving to a file, etc.

Comment: Ah, text selection is a good point that's a bit hard to handle manually in such scenarios.